# Segfault trying to work with shared_ptr in forward declared class

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, forward-declaration

I'm having an odd issue where when I forward declare a class and run it, it calls the constructor successfully but when it tries to work with a shared_ptr, it segfaults within the `__exchange_and_add` on `return __atomic_fetch_add` forward declared class constructor.

The class we're trying to use is located in a linked shared object.

For example:

```
class MyForwardDeclaredClass {
    public:
          MyForwardDeclaredClass();
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public:
            MyClass() { _myForwardDeclaredClass.reset(new MyForwardDeclaredClass()); }

            std::shared_ptr<MyForwardDeclaredClass> _myForwardDeclaredClass;
    }
}
```

[image]

But if I do this:

```
#include <MyForwardDeclaredClass.hpp>

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public:
            MyClass() { _myForwardDeclaredClass.reset(new MyForwardDeclaredClass()); }

            std::shared_ptr<MyForwardDeclaredClass> _myForwardDeclaredClass;
    }
}
```

It works properly.

Comment: The code you show is not obviously wrong. Your problem must be elsewhere. Side note: `class X { public: X(); };` is _not_ a forward declaration of `X`; it is a full definition. If that sequence of tokens is not exactly the same that is also in your header file (whose content you did not show), then you do something very wrong.

Comment: @j6t, It's exactly the same! I hit the constructor successfully. I guess I used the term 'forward declaration' incorrectly and it is as you said a 'full definition'.

Comment: Please post real code